# Running cmake from bash script

Tags: bash, cmake

I have a project which is build using cmake. I am trying to write a shell script for automating the build. But the trouble is, when run from the script the cmake is giving the following error

```
"include could not find load file:
            cmake/comp.cmake "
```

I tried to run the cmake from the terminal and its working fine. How can i get to run cmake from the shell script??

EDIT: cmake/comp.cmake is a file inside the project folder. which is actually an module i am loading in the cmakelists.txt

EDIT: the script

```
#!/bin/bash

num=$(grep -c "PATH=$PATH:/opt/robocomp/bin" ~/.bashrc)
if [ $num -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "export PATH=$PATH:/opt/robocomp/bin" >> ~/.bashrc;
    echo "added /opt/robocomp/bin to PATH ";
fi

source ~/.bashrc
cd ~/robocomp
cmake .
make
sudo make install

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 
    echo "/opt/robocomp/lib/" >> /etc/ld.so.conf
    sudo ldconfig
fi
```

Comment: Sounds like you're executing the script from the wrong directory.

Comment: no, i am in the right directory. i changed the directory before executing it.

Comment: Can you share corresponding part of your shell script?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add the path of directory which contains `comp.cmake` to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`. Add this line to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
list( APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake" )
```

and then include your module:

```
include( comp )
```

As side note: it is usually better use [out-of-source builds](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Out-of-source_build_trees).