# Execution CMake from within a Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, cmake

I've built a script to automate a CMake build of OpenCV4.  The relevant part of the script is written as:

**install.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
#...
cd /home/pi/opencv
mkdir build
cd build

cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D ENABLE_NEON=ON \
    -D ENABLE_VFPV3=ON \
    -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
    -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF ..
```

This part of the code is first executed from `/home/pi/` directory.  If I execute these lines within the cli they work and the cmake file is built without error.  If I run this same code form a bash script it results in the `cmake` command resulting in `-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!`.

I believe this is similar to these two SO threads ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56375416/bash-cant-launch-a-program-created-with-make-on-linux) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29234891/running-cmake-from-bash-script)) in as much as they both describe situations where calling a secondary script from the first script creates a problem (or at least that's what I think they are saying).  If that is the case, how can you start a script from `/parent/`, change to `/child/` within the script, execute secondary script (CMake) as though executed from the `/child/` directory?

If I've missed my actual problem - highlighting taht would be even more helpful.

**Update with Full Logs**

Output log for [CMakeOutput.log](https://gist.github.com/Llibyddap/e5d0cb139d3141fe2a439f08c6c19ea2) and [CMakeError.log](https://gist.github.com/Llibyddap/9537ed33054f6fbe050a2ab9e93f8b4f) as unsuccessfully run from the bash script.

When executed from the cli the successful logs are [success_CMakeOutput.log](https://gist.github.com/Llibyddap/1f297160cca32521b22859d566cdd73c) and [success_CMakeError.log](https://gist.github.com/Llibyddap/8203d2b71d8f4cff1074c9f77c373ecc)

**Update on StdOut**

I looked through the files above and they look the same...  Here is the [failed screen output](https://gist.github.com/Llibyddap/c8eca38bd6602d040cbe81c23c26281b) (noting the bottom lines) and the [successful screen output](https://gist.github.com/Llibyddap/0fd16fe5b5a73675ad28244174fa6014).

Comment: Message `-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!` means that some error(s) has occurred **before**. By itself, such message is not useful for debug the problem. Please, show us the message describing the first error.

Comment: You could explicitely add the source and build directories to the CMake call with `-S` and `-B` options. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Diagnostic: compare output of `env` from shell against output within script. Any differences may be relevant.

Comment: @bishop - yep, I was only focused on the failed logs...  I've attached both, but haven't yet (doing in now) compared.

Comment: `http://%3Cscript%20src=%22https://gist.github.com/Llibyddap/0fd16fe5b5a73675ad28244174fa6014.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E` - your links look invalid. Also, just in case, please __don't__ post links to text, this looks like a link to `gist.github`. Post the relevant text/messages in the question instead. I mean, the error is rather easy to find: `CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:288 (message):
  No modules has been found: /root/opencv_contrib/modules
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:370 (_glob_locations)
  modules/CMakeLists.txt:7 (ocv_glob_modules)`....

Comment: @KamilCuk - you're right - it is a gist, but the files are +1000 lines... :-s.  I think you're right on the error - i think that it is running from the `/` directory when from the script but from the `build` directory when I do it from the cli.  That's why I think the issue is the working directory not being passed to the CMake script... ?  Will do - on your follow comment - thanks.

Comment: This looks like you didn't remove the build directory before running cmake, so it picks the old cache. Remove CMakeCache.txt file or the build directory before re-configuring. And _please_ update your post to include the relevant information _as text_ in the question. It will help others that will try to search for the same problem _on this site_. `files are +1000 lines` - the whole output is not relevant  - the error message has like 5 ilnes. Did you clean the build directory before running cmake? How does `/root/opencv_contrib` end up in the logs? Are you running your script as root?

Comment: The `~/opencv_contrib/modules` references a user home directory, if `opencv_contrib` is in `/home/pi`, then replace the `~` with `/home/pi`. Or run it as a user that has proper `HOME` with that `opencv_contrib` folder.  Exactly, the output from the success is `/home/pi/opencv_contrib/modules`, you are running your script as a different user, so the path to opencv_contrib is invalid....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running your script as the `root` user with the `/root` home directory, while the `opencv_contrib` directory is in `/home/pi` directory. The `/home/pi` is most probably the home directory of the user `pi`.

Update the:

```
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
```

With proper path to `opencv_contrib`. Either provide `opencv_contrib` in the home directory of the root user, if you aim to run the script as root, or provide full, non-dependent on `HOME`, path to `opencv_contrib` directory.

```
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/pi/opencv_contrib/modules \
```

Comment: trying this now - - sorry, after you pointed it out it was incredibly obvious that I used the `~`.

Comment: Silly mistake - - spent hours looking for a "problem" under the hood.  Once again, turned out to be user error.  Thanks.